# Turn down TX power on AirPort?

Tags: macos, power, airport

Our floor has a blind spot so we needed to place an AirPort to cover two rooms. The AirPort in this particular room is transmitting at a higher power than needed, and its bleeding onto some areas where its unwanted. (This was found with [Wifi Stumbler](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.meraki.wifistumbler)).

I'm running the AirPort Utility on OS X Mavericks. The room in question has an AirPort Express. I've looked in the AirPort Utility, but I don't see where I can set TX power.

How do I turn down TX power on AirPort?

Is there some sort of secret knock to use with AirPort to get into advanced settings? Or should I be using something else to configure them?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In order to set the TX Power you need an older version of the Airport utility which is available [here](http://coreyjmahler.com/2013/10/24/airport-utility-5-6-1-on-os-x-10-9-mavericks/).

[image: wifitxpower]

Navigate to your base station > Manual Setup > AirPort > Wireless > Wireless Network Options. Once there, choose a transmit power that’s lower than 100% (you can choose between 10%, 25%, 50%, and 100%).

Remember to Update your configuration when you’re done.

---